# How to make android remote PowerPoint control app?

Tags: android, powerpoint, android-fragmentactivity, remote-desktop, android-bluetooth

I want to make an app to control PowerPoint via Wifi or Bluetooth.
Just an easy app like "click button" to go to the next Slide or  the previous Slide.
I googled and searched on stackoverflow, but could still not find a way to do it.
Can you show me the best way or an example to do that?
And should I connect via Wifi or Bluetooth, what is better and easier?
speacial thanks for your help

Comment: any more suggestion?

Comment: plz give me more suggest :(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [Anymote protocol](https://code.google.com/p/anymote-protocol/). While it was created for TV remotes, it can be used for other remotes as well, you just need fewer buttons. There is a [sample app](https://code.google.com/p/google-tv-remote/)  too